# generic fiber and global section

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a scheme over a ring $A$ which is a domain, $K = Frac(A)$ and let $F$ be quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$.

Is is true that $H^0(X,F) \otimes_A K = H^0(X_K,F_K)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. For instance if $X$ is an infinite disjoint union of copies of $\text{Spec }A$, say indexed by $I$, then $$H^0(X,\mathcal O_X) = \prod_I A,$$ $$H^0(X_K,(\mathcal O_X)_K) = H^0(X_K,\mathcal O_{X_K}) = \prod_I K$$

but it is not true in general that $(\prod_I A) \otimes_A K = \prod_I K$.